# What is the correct way how to create relation in typeorm?

Tags: typescript, entity-relationship, typeorm

I have two entities:

```
@Entity({ name: 'provider' })
export class ProviderEntity extends GenericEntity {

    @Column()
    name: string;

    @Column()
    description: string;

    @OneToMany(() => ItemEntity, item => item.provider)
    items: Promise<ItemEntity[]>;

}

@Entity({ name: 'item' })
export class ItemEntity extends GenericEntity {

    @Column()
    content: string;

    @ManyToOne(() => ProviderEntity, provider => provider.items)
    provider: Promise<ProviderEntity>;

}
```

`Provider` object already exist in database and I would like to create `item` with realtion to `provider`.

My code is:

```
        const content = 'mockContent';
        const providerId = '5be045b1-ef49-4818-b69f-a45c0b7e53';
       
        const item = new ItemEntity();
        item.content = content;
        item.provider = providerId; // ERROR

        await this.repository.save(item);
        return item;
```

The code it works, but I am getting an typescript error `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Promise<ProviderEntity>'.`. What is the correct way how to insert this?

---

Generic entity class contains only id

```
@PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
id: string;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe to associate things by a relation ID, and not a full relation object, you need to add the relation ID to your interface:

```
@ManyToOne(() => ProviderEntity, provider => provider.items)
provider: Promise<ProviderEntity>;

@Column()
providerId: string
```

`providerId` is the column TypeORM uses to keep track of the relation internally, you simply simply need to expose it publicly.

And then you simply set that property:

```
const item = new ItemEntity();
item.content = content;
item.providerId = providerId; // set providerId column directly.

await this.repository.save(item);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @alex-wayne who pointed out this question to me. For Reference, the approach which he proposed most likely originated from this [github issue](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/447). More precisely [this answer](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/447#issuecomment-298896602) from pleerock, the core contributor.

Moreover, I personally prefer the [first approach](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/447#issuecomment-298701681). In practice, with the addition to using the `create` method:

```
const content = 'mockContent';
const providerId = '5be045b1-ef49-4818-b69f-a45c0b7e53';

const provider = new Provider();
provider.id = providerId;
       
const item = this.itemRepository.create({ content, provider })

await this.repository.save(item);
```